# Migrate existing SQL Server database using roundhouse?

Tags: sql-server, roundhouse

I have a SQL Server database with data. I'm planning to implement Roundhouse in my project. How can I migrate existing table schema into Roundhouse table ?

Answer (score 1):

Another good alternative is using the powerup tool. It's part of the same chucknorris toolset and it will generate **[roundhouse anytime script formats](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/Anytimescripts)** for the following objects:

- stored procedures
- views
- functions

I didn't see an option to download a compiled .exe so had to download the source and build it locally. However, there were some issues I ran into that I had to clean up to successfully build the project. Also, I extended the project to include tables and constraints and place them in the **up** folders. I may try and fork the project and update the changes so others can leverage this tool to generate the table scripts in the future.

Here's a link to the repo: https://github.com/chucknorris/powerup

Answer (score 0):

I use Management Studio with Tasks -> Generate Scripts.
Then I modify those so that they check if the objects already exists and use it as the initial Up script.
Views script I have in roundhouse scripts folder